# How to insert a sitemap within a subsite when using Wordpress multisite

Tags: customization, multisite, uploads, sitemap

I have a multisite Wordpress site.
The structure of its URLs is currently the following:
mysite.com
mysite.com/subfolder/
Now, I know that I can put the sitemap of the first site (mysite.com) in the Wordpress root folder. In fact, I did and it works.
But where do I insert the sitemap of the second site (mysite.com/subfolder/)?

Thank you very much everyone in advance for any response, because it is important to me.

Comment: What do you mean with "put sitemap"? Do you manually generate a sitemap and place it in the FTP? If so, why? WP and/or SEO plugins should automatically generate these files for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sitemaps belong to a domain. Not sure if there is any special code that lets you extend the main site's sitemap, but you can always use the sitemao directive in `robots.txt` "file" of your domain, either by editting it "manually" (probably one of the SEO plugin can help with doing it without breaking anything) or by adding a plugin that will hook on the `'robots_txt'` filter and add it progrematically (which is how the main sitemap is added to it)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress generates sitemaps on the go, there's no need to create a new one, check for it on yourwebsite.com/wp-sitemap.xml